# Where is the registry key for the Access client setting "Ignore DDE requests"

Tags: ms-access, registrykey

I have an Access program that uses dde requests to open orders in another Access database.
This process suddenly stopped working for one client.  I am trying to debug what is going wrong.  It would be nice to know where that little switch is in the registry for when I look at his computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645), the registry value on my machine (Access 2010) appears to be

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Settings\Ignore DDE Requests

It originally didn't exist, but when I selected the option in Access the registry value was created as REG_DWORD with a value of 1.

Comment: thanks for the how to link there.  I will be using that next time I need info like that.